# Can't Create Content Type

Tags: 7, nodes

This is from the node_example from the Examples module on Drupal.org, I cut most part of them off now this should be an edited version of node_example.install: http://newstartpoint.com/public/node_example.install.txt

Now this is what I managed to get by myself: This http://newstartpoint.com/public/tudou_update.install.txt. This above one works but the one I programmed doesn't. Can anyone give me some ideas? They seem pretty much identical.

Thanks!

Comment: the problem is in hook_install or hook_update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because of overriding 'base' property, change it to 'node_content'

> using the "base" return component of hook_node_info() as the function
>   prefix. For example, poll.module defines the base for the Poll content
>   type as "poll", so during creation of a poll node, hook_insert() is
>   only invoked by calling poll_insert().

Comment: Exactly, after changing the base the content type was created. However I think the documentation is quite misunderstanding. Thanks!

Comment: Yep mostly appreciated :)